# Show Downloads folder on the Dock as fan instead of opening immediately

Tags: macos, mojave, dock

I am trying to get the Downloads folder on my dock in the Fan view, as seen in this picture:

[image: Fan view of Downloads folder]

However, when I click on the folder, the folder immediately opens instead.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when you click the folder in the dock? More specifically, does it open Finder or a popup with a grid of each file?

Comment: It could be that you are using an alias to the folder instead of the folder itself, which always opens in a Finder window. Could you enlarge your dock and screenshot your desktop or your dock?

Comment: I posted pic of my desktop

Comment: @haykam when I click it opens the download folder not a grid of each file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the download folder you added to the dock. Right click on that folder and do get info. In the pane that opens there should be a line that says "Original" with the location of the actual downloadeds folder. Go to that downloads folder and drag it to the dock area where the other download folder is located. Remove that first download folder from the dock and place this new download folder there instead. Now you should be able to set it up as a fan.

Comment: Glad i could help!